# error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘__extension__’

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors

I am having a strange compile time error message when attempting to compile one of the  files in my codebase.

What makes this error more wierd is that it only occurs when I'm building in release mode - it compiles with no problem in Debug mode.

Below is the (entire) content of the offending file:

```
#include <string.h>

char * strtok_r(char *s, const char *delim, char **save_ptr)
{
  char *token;

  if (s == NULL)
    s = *save_ptr;

  s += strspn (s, delim);
  if (*s == '\0')
    return NULL;

  token = s;
  s = strpbrk (token, delim);
  if (s == NULL)
    *save_ptr = strchr (token, '\0');
  else
    {
      *s = '\0';
      *save_ptr = s + 1;
    }
  return token;
}
```

I am compiling with gcc (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3 on Ubuntu 10.0.4

Does anyone know why I am getting this error?

Comment: I can compile this with no problems. 1.Is this the real complete file? 2.Doesn't the compiler give you a line number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cant use the name `strtok_r` for your function name since it is already in the string.h library.  Compiles fine if you use `strtok_rrr` or something.

Comment: But do you kno why it works in Debug mode and breaks only in Release mode?

Comment: @Ashish i don't know what debug/release is in this context. Is it just with -g or no optimizations, or using some build system?